# android activity is crashing when changing text in view

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do some really basic things and I think I'm making a little mistake that I can't see. I just want to change the text in a hello_world generated android project
Here is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView helloWorld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewName);

        if(helloWorld != null){
            String str =(String) helloWorld.getText();
            Log.d("ViewText",str);
            helloWorld.setText(seq);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

and here is my xml file of the UI

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.strreview.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem is that the application wont even run, it crash when I try to change the text. So if anyone see the problem here it will be helpful. I've already check with other similar question and I don't see where is the difference.

////Stack Trace////

> 06-06 09:46:18.061: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(30784): Parent view is not
>   a TextView 06-06 09:46:18.081: D/AndroidRuntime(30784): Shutting down
>   VM 06-06 09:46:18.081: W/dalvikvm(30784): threadid=1: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x41707c08) 06-06 09:46:18.081:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-06 09:46:18.081:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30784): Process: com.example.strreview, PID: 30784
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.strreview/com.example.strreview.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 06-06 09:46:18.081:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 06-06
>   09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-06
>   09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 06-06 09:46:18.081:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476) 06-06
>   09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-06
>   09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 06-06 09:46:18.081:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 06-06
>   09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-06 09:46:18.081:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30784): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   com.example.strreview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5473) 06-06
>   09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
>   06-06 09:46:18.081: E/AndroidRuntime(30784):  ... 11 more 06-06
>   09:46:18.096: I/Process(30784): Sending signal. PID: 30784 SIG: 9

Comment: *"I don't know why it doesn't work"* is not a useful title for a question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1. Publish the full stacktrace 2. `helloWorld.setText(seq);` --> I don't see where `seq` is declared

Comment: Why are you making a call to fragment manager?  It isn't needed.  And most likely seq is null causing an error, but since you didn't post a log, who knows?

Comment: this is auto generated code from eclipse, and the seq is only a charsequence declare on top

Comment: Can you paste complete stack trace here ?

Comment: Everything works fine until i try to change the text of the view

Comment: What is "seq"?  Has it been initialized?

Comment: Which line in your onCreate() is line 38?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think thats because your TextView isnt in your xml: activity_main, you should add a TexView to this XML.

Comment: I wonder why this is the problem but it actually solve everything. This was all generated by eclipse and I assumed that everything was supposed to be ok

Comment: Thats because you try to setText to a TextView that isnt in your activity_main, you were trying to access the xml of you PlaceholderFragment instead of your Activity

Comment: I understand it now, but I don't know why it's generated like this for an hello world, on every example I've found they never mentioned it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with TextView `Parent view is not a TextView` there is no TextView and you are trying to access it. So its giving `java.lang.NullPointerException`